# Parámetro Tiempo Ejecución Global Scala

Tags: scala

Tengo un objeto `job` que implementa el método `main` y recupera un parámetro `args` del tiempo de ejecución:

```
object job{
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit{
      val param = args(0)
   }
}
```

Posteriormente, en otro objeto, necesito usar ese mismo parámetro de ejecución contenido en `param`. ¿Alguna forma de poder recuperar el parámetro en otro objeto que no implemente el `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de nada, habría que preguntarse *¿qué vería ese otro objeto de no haberse ejecutado antes la función `main` de tu objeto?*

Este parámetro tiene que ser un atributo público de tu objeto. Además, se ha de poder modificar, así que tiene que ser *mutable*:

```
object Job {                            
  var param: String = ""                  

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    param = args(0)                         
  }                                       
}
```

Se accedería como `Job.param` y podrían se modificado por cualquier otro objeto, cosa que igual no es deseable.

Además, al estar inicializado como cadena vacía (`""`) sería indistiguible a si hubieras pasado una cadena vacía como primer argumento.

Por lo tanto, es mejor proteger los cambios de `param`. Lo más fácil es usar accesores:

```
object Job {
  private var _param = ""
  def param = _param

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    _param = args(0)
  }
}
```

Para poder distinguir si efectivamente está sin definir o no, podríamos haber usado `null` como valor inicial. Pero en scala es mejor evitarlo y usar `Options`, mucho más seguro:

```
object Job {
  private var _param:Option[String] = None
  def param = _param

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    _param = Some(args(0))
  }
}
```

---

Nota de estilo: en scala los nombres de objetos se aconsejan que estén capitalizados, igual que se hace con las clases.